# PHP shell_exec ssh-add ssh-agent could not open connection to authentication agent

Tags: ssh, php, ssh-agent

I did this

```
shell_exec('eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" 2>&1');
shell_exec('ssh-add /opt/.ssh/id_rsa 2>&1');
```

and still getting error connecting to authentication agent. The first line successfully outputs the agent id.

Any ideas why and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/shell_exec) function runs your commands in a shell and after they end, the shell ends too (therefore also all the environment variables will get lost).

With the second invocation, new shell is invoked without the environment variables pointing to the running `ssh-agent` and therefore it is no wonder it does fail.

There are various possibilities how to resolve this:

- The easiest is to run both commands in a single shell:

  ```
  shell_exec('eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" 2>&1 && ssh-add /opt/.ssh/id_rsa 2>&1');
  ```
- The other is to parse the environment variables directly in PHP, set them to the environment of your script so they are passed to the next shell (hopefully).
- The last one makes something similar as the previous one, but passes the environment as part of the next `shell_exec()`, because in the first line, you don't need that `eval`, but it it is essential in the second one:

  ```
  $str = shell_exec('$(ssh-agent -s)');
  shell_exec('eval "' . $str . '"; ssh-add /opt/.ssh/id_rsa 2>&1');
  ```